# pywin32 and excel. Exception when writing large quantities of data

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

I am currently trying to write a large amount of data to an excel spreadsheet using the pywin32 libraries. As a simple example of the problem that I am facing take the following code to generate a 1000 cell x 1000 cell multiplication table.

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as c

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")                             
xl.Visible = True
Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
Sheets = Workbook.Sheets

tableSize = 1000

for i in range(tableSize):
    for j in range(tableSize):
        Sheets(1).Cells(i+1, j+1).Value = i*j
```

For small values this works. However, for larger values the python program eventually crashes with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Example.py", line 16, in <module>
    Sheets(1).Cells(i+1, j+1).Value = i*j
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 474, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs)) pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146777998), None)
```

I've already admitted defeat due to the fact that this is significantly slower than xlwt but I am still curious as to what is happening to cause this error.

Comment: is that large negative value the value you put in? how large of values are we talking about?

Comment: No it is not. The largest value that the program should enter into a spread sheet is 1M but it never gets that far. As far as I can tell that large negative number somehow corresponds to an error code that indicates a general error. EDIT: I have done other searches for that error code and have found a wide array of problems but none seem to be very similar to mine besides the fact that it is related to using pywin32.

Comment: If it helps any one who comes here looking for a solution to this problem. Adding a check and wait for each cell significantly increases the time the program runs and the number of cells written. e.g.  `while Sheets(1).Cells(i+1, j+1).Value != i*j: pass` However, the program will still crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out.

The error only occurred when the user interacted with excel window while code was running. By adding `xl.Interactive = False` before doing any work with excel this can be avoided. If this is added before the application is visible there is no chance of any interaction.

So the final code is:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import constants as c

xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Interactive = False
xl.Visible = True
Workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add()
Sheets = Workbook.Sheets

Sheets(1).Cells(1,2).Value = "Test"
print Sheets(1).Cells(1,2).Value

tableSize = 1000

for i in range(tableSize):
    for j in range(tableSize):
            Sheets(1).Cells(i+1, j+1).Value = i*j
```

Comment: Thanks it helped, but it should be xl.Interactive = True