# Microsoft Excel cannot access the file from python using win 32 but the file exists and the path is correct

Tags: python, excel, winapi

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    
      File "<ipython-input-19-eed7c559bf73>", line 25, in <module>
        wb.SaveAs(r'C:\Users\maria isabel\Desktop\Clases Particulares\Python\Proyecto_Jose\25_06_2020\Resultado.xlsx')
    
      File "C:\Users\maria\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.7\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\_Workbook.py", line 288, in SaveAs
        , Local, WorkIdentity)
    
    com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Microsoft Excel no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\\Users\\maria isabel\\Desktop\\Clases Particulares\\Python\\Proyecto_Jose\\25_06_2020\\AE044300'. Puede haber varios motivos:\n\n• El nombre o la ruta del archivo no existen.\n• Otro programa está usando el archivo.\n• El libro que está intentando guardar tiene el mismo nombre que otro libro que está abierto en estos momentos.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

This is the problem I have, im trying this code:

```
import string
import win32com.client as win32

excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
ws = wb.Worksheets("Spot")

rows = Resultados_Modelo_spot.shape[0]

# ws.Range(f"A2:A{rows}").Value = Resultados_Modelo_spot.index

letras = string.ascii_uppercase
letras = letras[1:14]

cont_paginas = 0

for index, column in enumerate(letras):
        for fila in range(rows):
              
            ws.Range(f"A{fila + 2}:A{fila + 2}").Value = Resultados_Modelo_spot.index[fila]
            ws.Range(f"{column}{fila+2}:{column}{fila + 2}").Value = Resultados_Modelo_spot.iloc[fila, index]

wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, path_to_pdf2)
wb.SaveAs(r'C:\Users\maria isabel\Desktop\Clases Particulares\Python\Proyecto_Jose\25_06_2020\Resultado.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

But it always shows me that error. Actually the code runs and creates the xlsx, but I would like to know how to avoid this message in my terminal. When I do listdir of my current directory the name of the file appears and it is not opened in other place (I verified this with the task manager).

Comment: could it be the issue of the space between `maris isabel`. in linux you have to escape it by `\`, look it up for windows

Comment: Could you provide wb_path to help understand the problem?

Comment: wb_path = r'C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Escritorio\Private Classes\Python\Proyecto_Jose\Plantilla\Plantilla2.xlsx'
path_to_pdf2 = r'C:\Users\maria\OneDrive\Escritorio\Private Classes\Python\Proyecto_Jose\Plantilla\PDFs\Resultados.pdf'

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be that the `SaveAs` function is not compatible with the new version of Excel, try to modify `wb.SaveAs()` to `wb.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs()`

Comment: Is it abnormal due to too much data written to Excel? Maybe you can refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836319/pywin32-and-excel-exception-when-writing-large-quantities-of-data